# Process terminated with status

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

i am running into this error: **Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 16 second(s))** every time am trying to run a c++ file circle.h in code::blocks, here is the log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in GraphicsTest (compiler: tdm64-gcc 64-bit Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=gnu++98 -m32 -Og -IC:\TDM-GCC-32\lib\graphics -IC:\TDM-GCC-32\lib\winbgim -IC:\TDM-GCC-32\include\winbgim -IC:\TDM-GCC-32\include\graphics -c "C:\Users\Jones Mwakisha\Documents\Programming\Cpp\GraphicsTest\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\TDM-GCC-64\lib -LC:\TDM-GCC-32\include -o bin\Debug\GraphicsTest.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32 -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -static -m32 -lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32  C:\TDM-GCC-32\lib\libbgi.a C:\TDM-GCC-32\include\graphics.h C:\TDM-GCC-32\include\winbgim.h
Output file is bin\Debug\GraphicsTest.exe with size 1.72 MB


Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
 

-------------- Run: Debug in GraphicsTest (compiler: tdm64-gcc 64-bit Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: C:\Users\Jones Mwakisha\Documents\Programming\Cpp\GraphicsTest\bin\Debug\GraphicsTest.exe
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\TDM-GCC-64\lib;C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin;C:\TDM-GCC-32;C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin
Executing: "C:\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "C:\Users\Jones Mwakisha\Documents\Programming\Cpp\GraphicsTest\bin\Debug\GraphicsTest.exe"  (in C:\Users\Jones Mwakisha\Documents\Programming\Cpp\GraphicsTest\.)
Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 16 second(s))
```

Here is the file

```
#include <graphics.h>
int main()
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm, (char*)"");
    circle(160,120, 100);
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The value `-1073741819` is the same as `0xC0000005`, which means your program crashed due to an access violation.

Comment: You probably have this problem because your compiler is too new. Remember that the WinBGIm port was compiled with gcc-3.4.5 in 2005. Newer compilers may not be compatible with this very old / obsolete code.